# Clear Screen in "watch" Command

Tags: linux, bash

I commonly run a lot of programs from the same shell before using the watch command to monitor the programs for completion. (I filter the ps command a bit, but this example is simpler.)

```
sleep 10 && for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done &
watch -n 5 ps aux
```

The watch command clears the terminal so that the output of the command is clear and there is no clutter.

[image: Output of watch command]

When another program outputs such as the echo statements in the example, the result is a little weird. It prints strangely and the results seem to depend on the size of the output. Even though watch should have rerun the "ps aux" command, it does not overwrite the output of the "echo" commands.

[image: After sleep timer has finished]

Is there something like this that would prevent the output of other programs from covering watch output?

```
watch -n 5 ClearScreenSomehow && ps aux
```

Comment: As written, this problem is not reproducible so it is difficult to help you. You'll need to add an example program that reproduces the undesirable behavior.

Comment: Separate note, why does your binary have an `exe` extension on Linux? It doesn't hurt but it does seem a little strange and unnecessary.

Comment: @merlin2011 I changed out the commands to make it so you can easily repeat the problem on your own terminal. I guess the exe thing is just a force of habit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a *simple* way to do this. Until someone comes up with one, here's a *complicated* way to do this:

Consider the original case as control:

```
#delayed print to clutter up watch later
bash -c 'sleep 10; echo ASDF' &
#watch dummy command, observe cluttering
watch -n1 'ls -la |head -25'
```

My approach is to hijack all the processes that can clutter up your window, and throw their output into the abyss that is `/dev/null`.

A standard way of redirecting the output of already running processes is [using `gdb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593764/5067311). In order to do it non-interactively, you have to use [the `-batch` switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181664/5067311) and a manual specification of the `pid` you want to redirect. The result is

```
bash -c 'sleep 10; echo ASDF' &
#sudo gdb -p "$!" -batch -ex 'p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),1)' -ex 'p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),2)' -ex 'detach'
gdb -p "$!" -batch -ex 'p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),1)' -ex 'p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),2)' -ex 'detach'
watch -n1 'ls -la |head -25'
```

where `$!` is the `pid` of the last spawned process, which is just what we need in our example. In your actual use case you'd have to [loop over every `pid` running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18868046/5067311) of your given shell, and substitute each `pid` into `$!` above.

Also note that the `gdb` call should work without `sudo` for your own processes, but for some reason (stemming from some configuration) it only let me perform it with `sudo`. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and obvious answer is to not run background commands which can produce output without redirection.

When you run something in the background, have it print to a file.  Examine the file when you wish to see the output.

Some people also like to use `screen` or `tmux` to run separate jobs in separate virtual terminals.  Or just open a separate `xterm` or similar for each process you want to run while doing something else.

Comment: Usually if I allow something to print to std out it is intentional. Maybe I watch the output to see if the program gets past the point where it crashed before and then it is okay to leave it and come back later. Other times, programs I was not expecting print error messages such as my IDE. I suppose I could append `> /dev/null` to all these calls, but it is somewhat tedious.